# How to import globally scss mixins into create react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Please tell me, is it possible to globally import a library with mixins or variables into the create react app **without using eject**?

I have a grid, let it be a Bootstrap preprocessor grid that gives mixins for generating grid elements - containers, rows and columns, that is, like this:

```
.myContainer {
  @include make-container();
  @include make-container-max-widths();
}

.myRow {
  @include make-row();
}
.myCol {
  background-color: yellow;
  @include make-col-ready();
  @include make-col(4);
  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    @include make-col(6);
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
    @include make-col(12);
  }
}
```

I use css module for styles in react and I would like to have access to this mixin in every css module - I can’t find a solution.

Now I’m doing this - in each module I import these mixins at the beginning

```
@import "./grid/index.scss";
```

And then the mixins work inside the module.

But the mixin code is duplicated in each of the css modules in dev mode - mixins bring the same code to the   tags

[style duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Ctp.jpg)

Is it possible to specify once what needs to be imported and just use mixins in those css modules where necessary?